# Sort Date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, wcf, xamarin.android

hi i have 2 tables on my database i am using mysql for my database and WCF for web service to host my android app. Below is Announce table

```
AnnounceId| Title           |Message               |Date Sent
0         |meeting          |Meeting On 11/25/2014 |09/28/2014
1         |Emergency Meeting|Meeting Tommorrow     |10/5/2014
```

Disconnection Table

```
NoticeId|Date Sent |Amount
0       |09/30/2014|74.2
1       |10/06/2014|84.0
```

i use this table when i sent notification to my mobile app, im just a student, My question is how do i joint this two table and sort them by date.

```
AnnounceId | NoticeId | Date
0          | null     |09/28/2014
null       | 0        |09/30/2014
1          | null     |10/5/2014
null       | 1        |10/06/2014
```

Or do you have any different approach or better than this. please do suggest thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a `union all`:

```
select AnnounceId, NULL as NoticeId, DateSent as Date
from Announce
union all
select NULL, NoticeId, Date
from Disconnection
order by Date;
```

Comment: Thank you, what if i want to add another table is this applicable?

Comment: i want to add another table name `billing` add this column `BillingId` and `Date`

Comment: Solve it, Thank you very much, u save my ass this is my query with 3 tables `select AnnounceId, NULL as NoticeId, NULL as BillingId, Date FROM tblannounce UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NoticeId, NULL, Date FROM tblnotice_disconnection UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, BillingId, Date FROM tblconsumer_billing ORDER BY DATE DESC`